# how can I reinstall my wireless drivers for bcm broadcomm 4311

Tags: installation, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I am using ubuntu 12.10, and I got the broadcomm 4311 bcm drivers working by the help from one of the ask ubuntu sites, but now for some reason the laptop looses connection on its own, while other pc's and laptops have no problem whatsoever. The connection comes and goes. It can't be the network as other computer on wireless doesn't have this problem. Can it be the drivers acting up? How can I reinstall them? Please assist, its really frustrating. I don't know what else what to do.

Comment: Before we propose an answer, let's identify your exact device. Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: lspci -nn -d 14e4:

Comment: Thanks, I tried to enter this above command, but it says that some command are missing after the "-d". How do I enter this command? with the 14e4 also? I am not sure, looks maybe I entered it incorrectly.

Comment: I did however manage with other commands to get these info on what type of wireless card and system I'm using: 10:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01) 

network 
       description: Wireless interface 
       physical id: 1 
       logical name: wlan0 
       serial: 00:1a:73:93:f1:6c 
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless 
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=b43 driverversion=3.5.0-39-generic firmware=666.2 ip=192.168.0.7 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg

Comment: The command would be all of what I said in one long line. However, we see the information we need. You have the correct driver. Let's see what's going wrong in this command: dmesg | grep -e wlan -e 80211 > oros.txt  Find the file oros.txt in your user directory and paste it here and give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com/  That funny pipe symbol | is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with \.

Comment: Thanks, is this a command:dmesg | grep -e wlan -e 80211 > oros.txt? I am not sure what I must do. Sorry about that.

Comment: Exactly! One long command with symbols, spaces, etc. exactly as you have. No worries, I was a beginner once, too.

Comment: thanks, what is the "oros.txt" for? as the orosjopie is only my username for askubuntu.

Comment: The file just has to have a name so you can find it in your user directory easily. You may name it anything. How about chili.txt? Or coldbeer.txt? It doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi, I just pasted the contents of the file it created and the link is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5988886/ and I used my username for ask ubuntu also in the ubuntu pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

We see the wireless device attempting to roam between two different access points; one with a MAC address of xx:xx:72:7d and one with a MAC address of xx:xx:17:7c. Please run the terminal command:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

You will see a listing of the access points available at your location. Determine which is your preferred access point and make note of its MAC address. Now right-click the Network Manager icon and select 'Edit Connections.' Select Wireless. Fill in the desired MAC address in the space for BSSID and check 'Connect Automatically.'[image]

We also see your regulatory domain changing from GB to ZA. Let's edit one file to set the domain in your location. Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above the line exit 0 please add:

```
iw reg set GB
```

Of course, substitute your two-digit country code from here if it isn't GB. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. Now reboot with these two changes and tell us if it is fixed.

If any part of this is unclear, please ask me.

Comment: Thank you, this line "iw reg set GB" are you saying that I change GB with mine country's code which is ZA? Or do I keep it at GB?

Comment: If your country code is ZA, then set the /etc/rc.local to ZA. I am just concerned that the wireless card is spending all day flip-flopping back and forth and not connecting or staying connected.